# SQL - Splitting the string

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to split a string(eg. BUFORD GA 30518) based on spaces to fill into different fields City, State and zipcode. Please help me in writing Query for this in SQL

Comment: @alisha anjum Check and mark as correct if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT  City= LEFT(Column, CHARINDEX(' ',Column)-1)
,State= LEFT(SUBSTRING(Column, CHARINDEX(' ',Column)+1,LEN(Column)), CHARINDEX(' ',SUBSTRING(Column, CHARINDEX(' ',Column)+1,LEN(Column)))-1)
,zipcode= REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(Column), CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(Column))-1))
```

**You can try this:**

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column_one, '[^ ]+', 1, 1) col_one,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column_one, '[^ ]+', 1, 2) col_two,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.column_one, '[^ ]+', 1, 3) col_three
FROM YOUR_TABLE t;
```

**Can try this also:**

```
SELECT SUBSTR(t.column_one, 1, INSTR(t.column_one, ' ')-1) AS col_one,
       SUBSTR(t.column_one, INSTR(t.column_one, ' ')+1) AS col_two,
       SUBSTR(t.column_one, INSTR(t.column_one, ' ')+1) AS col_three
FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

Comment: Hi, can this be modified to be written in oracle as well?

Comment: @alishaanjum I had updated the answer, try this. Mark it as useful if it works for you

Comment: Thanks alot. It is very useful.

Comment: @alishaanjum Mark it as useful if it worked out for you

Comment: @alishaanjum I'm glad that it worked out for you